# what is the need to rebuild all project or a part of the project?

Tags: c, build, rebuild

What does the 'Rebuild all' button or the 'Build' in IDE's like DEV C++ do actually?I never needed it but I've seen people using it.This is different from 'compile'(compiling is building in code blocks but not in DEV c++).

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual or googling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compiling and building is not the same. Compiling means translating your source (e.g. c-code) to a binary format or some sort of byte-code. Build means the entire process of building a project. E.g. if you have more than one c-file these files needs to be compiled first and linked afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

The first time you compile, you need to compile every C file. On subsequent compiles, you only need to compile the C files that have changed.

The project can keep track of what had been modified and what needs to be recompiled and what doesn't.

So Build can be faster, as it won't recompile everything, only the source files that have changed since last build.

Re-build all forces everything to be recompiled, which might be necessary if some sort of change is made that the project can't identify for some reason, like a change to a file made externally to the IDE.